# Passive form of “John is painting his room"

Tags: passive-voice

What is the passive form of the statement "John is painting his room."? I do guess the correct form is "His room is being painted by John". But I am unsatisfied with that as it sounds a little absurd. What is the correct passive form of the statement?

Comment: The answer this question got [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/109843/passive-form-of-john-is-painting-his-room) would clear it up

Answer (score 5):

Usually we'd write this as passive to avoid specifying agency:

> John's room was being painted.

But that implies that John isn't the one doing the painting, so you need the awkward *by him*:

> John's room was being painted *by him.*

But *him* can't bind to *John*, so this is unlikely.  It still sounds like someone else was doing the painting.  Let's try it the other way around:

> His room is being painted by John.

Now *him* **really** can't bind to *John*, because it comes first!  It sounds like John is painting someone else's room.  This is no good.

If we want to use the passive *and* specify agency *and* specify that John is both the painter and the owner of the room, we need to be explicit:

> John's room is being painted by John.

But this is still clumsy.  There has to be some **reason** we're converting to passive, because it's not natural to do so in this situation.  It can't be to avoid specifying who's doing the painting, so more likely, it's to **emphasize** who's doing the painting.

Unfortunately, the emphasis doesn't come across in the above sentence, so it still doesn't feel natural.  It's possible to read it aloud in a natural way (stressing the words *by John*), but the emphasis isn't clear in writing.  We can fix that by being more explicit about it:

> John's room is being painted *by John*.

Or, slightly better:

> John's room is being painted--by John himself.

Of course, this probably isn't the answer your exam was looking for!

Comment: 's last suggestion is exactly what I would have suggested (though I wouldn't have put the hyphens personally).

Answer (score 2):

In my estimation, you're correct on both accounts.  "His room is being painted by John." is the most direct way of expressing this in the passive, and it sounds more than a little absurd.  "John's room is being painted by him." is even less satisfying.

My advice would be to avoid the need for such a statement if at all possible.

Comment: Ya i do agree that the need for such statements that sound absurd must be avoided. But, the question was asked in an entrance examination for scholarship, and I had no way out to escape. So, I wrote the first one, but still I am confused if I had committed a mistake. Anyway, thank you!